# Hash algorithm used in Lucene Indexing

Tags: hash, lucene, indexing

Any idea which hash algorithm is used while Indexing each word in lucene

Answer (score 0):

Lucene doesn't use hashing to lookup terms, they are stored lexicographically in a file called Term Dictionary. Another file, called the Term Info Index is loaded into memory in order to provide random access to the Term Dictionary (which is basically a skip list).

More information on [Lucene website](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_3_0/fileformats.html#Term%20Dictionary).

Currently, the Term Info Index stores the position of every indexdivisor-th (indexdivisor=128 typically) in memory, meaning you can lookup a term by performing one binary search on the Term Info Index (in memory), and at most 128 entry scans on the Term Dictionary (on disk).

- http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Understanding-lucene-indexes-and-disk-I-O-td714698.html

There is an optimisation, currently available in trunk, for this Term Info Index, which uses a prefix [trie](http://en.wikipedia/org/wiki/Trie) in order to perform lookups and performs much better for terms dictionary-intensive queries.

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-3030